# Only one connectionstring from app.config is found

Tags: c#, connection-string, app-config

So I have app.config with three connectionstrings in my WPF project:

```
<connectionStrings>
        <clear/>
        <add name="Production" connectionString="Data Source=LAPTOP-R1\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=VIP_R_PROD;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False"/>
        <add name="Test" connectionString="Data Source=LAPTOP-R1\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=VIP_R_TEST;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False"/>
        <add name="ProductionMySQL" connectionString="removed for security"/>
    </connectionStrings>
```

When I try to access the two strings below the first in any way (index or name) it returns null.
The top string is accessible both by name and by index.

When using this:

```
 MessageBox.Show(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings.Count.ToString());
```

it will always return  value "1";

Comment: Check if the app.config is copied in the output directory with the correct name (your_application_name.exe.config)

Comment: Hey @Steve, it isn't. It gets stored as `App.config`. Any ideas?

Comment: Usually the file _app.config_ is copied during the build process to the output directory defined in the _output path_ property of the project itself and renamed as your__application_name.exe.config_ overwriting previous versions.  This is done at each build. If you don't see the exe.config file or if it is an outdated version then something is blocking this mechanism, Possibly a read-only exe.config file or something different in the properties of the app.config file registered in the project structure. (My defaults are: _Build Action=None_, _Copy to output directory=Do Not Copy_) etc.

Comment: You can try to create a new WinForms application and check if there are differences in the areas I hava told you in the previous comment

Comment: I just found a file called "[appname].dll.config", but the results stay the same.

Comment: So your app is not an exe but a library. In that case your configuration should be added to the main config file, the one used by the exe project not the library one.

Comment: My app consists of 2 libraries and 2 wpf projects. Both wpf projects get the "dll.config" file added but the results stay the same. And it still strikes me as very odd that only the top most string is found, the others are not.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved it by doing the following:

- Updated Visual Studio to 16.7.2 from 16.6.x
- Removed all bin and obj folders from all layers